# Websphere convert HTTP Header

Tags: rest, http-headers, websphere, apache-wink

i have a problem with HTTP- Header parameters on websphere. 
I have a Apache Wink Client and i send a REST- POST to the server. (Webspere 8.0.0.8 there is Wink, too)

On this server i have a GZIP Filter, that searchs the Content-Encoding parameter "gzip". My Problem is that the content parameter "Content-Encoding" has in my filter the parametername "$WSZIP" with my orginial value "gzip".

I cant find something about this.

PS. When i send a parameter like "test" the parameter doesnt change. Only Content-Encoding gets another name in it.

PS. on my testproject with tomcat & glassfish all works fine.

Comment: Do you use the Java Proxy in WAS?

Comment: No there is no proxy.